# Reflection is not a collineation

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Could you give me a collineation that proves that you can't construct the reflection of a line $e$ across a parallel line $f$ with a straightedge only? (That is, a collineation that maps $e$ and $f$ to parallel lines but where the image of the refelction of $e$ is not the same as the reflection of the image of $e$ across the image of $f$.)

Comment: Is the ruler marked or unmarked? (The term for an unmarked ruler being a straight-edge)

Comment: @Axoren it's a straight-edge